# Converter valor float, double ou single em DateTime

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Estava tendo problemas de **Cast** quando executava uma lambda e serializava para o serviço. Bem, a solução foi passar tudo para String e consegui. Do outro lado(App Android) eu pego e faço o que tem que ser feito. Bem, acontece que esse cliente tem suas datas carregadas no banco como um float, como essa aí(**79018**). Acontece que quando eu dou um `float.Parse(data_string)` e depois um `Convert.ToDateTime(floatvalue)`, dá o erro de cast dizendo que não dá para fazer o cast de Double para Single. Se coloco para single, continua o erro, o mesmo problema que estava tendo antes, que me gerou alguns posts aqui. Como eu transforma esse valor em DateTime?

```
private void listaLibera_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var libera = e.SelectedItem as Liberacao;
            DateTime datas = Convert.ToDateTime(float.Parse(libera.DataLib));

            lblTipoVenda.Text = "Tipo de Venda: " + libera.TipoVenda;
            //lblVencimento.Text = "Vencimento: " + (Convert.ToDateTime(libera.Vendedor)).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
            lblJuros.Text = "Juros: " + libera.Juros.ToString();
            lblEntrada.Text = "Entrada: " + libera.Entrada;
            lblAcrescimo.Text = "Acréscimo: " + libera.Acrescimo;
            lblDesconto.Text = "Desconto: " + datas.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
        }
```

Eu peguei o valor literal e tentei converter e continua o erro de **cast**, dessa forma: `Convert.ToDateTime(79018.0f)`.

Comment: Precisa ver o código, meios de reproduzir o problema. De qualquer forma acho que nunca vi um banco de dados tão mal estruturado como este. Já tinha visto um que as colunas eram todas palavrões que causava menos problema que este.

Comment: estou com esse problema de Cast já muito tempo. Tive que fazer uma gambi, para continuar meu trabalho. Sempre que carregava um valor float ou double do banco e quando atribuia a propriedade em minha DTO, dava esse erro e não resolvi. O que eu fiz foi passar tudo para string e assim pude continuar, mas não é o que eu desejo, mas tive que fazer assim

Comment: O sistema deles foi desenvolvido em Clarion e acho que é por isso que está em forma numérica e não em formato de datas e já existe há mais de 15 anos.

Comment: Não consigo fazer isso dentro do xamarin.forms: `var datas = DateTime.FromOADate(meu_double)`. Não reconhece o **FromOADate**

Comment: Será que essa data não está no formato de milisegundos? Se for isso, tente usar var time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, isso eu não sei dizer, mas se fizer isso no BD: `convert(datetime, 79018-36163) as DataLib` eu obtenho isso: `2017-05-02 00:00:00.000`. 79018 equivale ao campo `DataLib`

Comment: @pnet olha [esse gist](https://gist.github.com/Ambalus/48bcf15f9fc567ad0ea3), ele explica do porque do cálculo. Acho que o caminho vai ser mais ou menos esse. Vou colocar um código como resposta para ver se ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo [este gist](https://gist.github.com/Ambalus/48bcf15f9fc567ad0ea3), a data em Clarion considera o número de dias que se passaram desde 28/12/1800. Então seguindo a lógica, vai dar a data da seguinte forma:

```
new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(79018).ToShortDateString();
```

Me corrijam se estiver errado, por favor.

Comment: Vou fazer esse teste e assim que eu tiver o resultado, eu posto.

Comment: Na mosca, CDS Informática. Problema resolvido. Eu estava começando a ler alguma coisa sobre o Clarion, mas agredeço pela antecipação.